# Auto calculate total value laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

i have a problem where the value isn't calculated.
I have function where the user able to update Weight/size and quantity(if the input isn't in readonly). When the user enter a new weight/size it will be auto-calculated in the Order Total. Apparently, there is a value already in the Order Total (since it is an update) so i want it to auto update the value in the order total when the user update the new input in weight/size or quantity.
[pls click this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yehFO.png)

here is my updates.blade.php

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-actions">  
                <div class="container" style="padding: 0;margin: 0;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" >
                    <span class="float-sm-left">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Update Order</h3>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </br>
                <form action="" method="POST" >
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="validationTooltip01">Order ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="orderID" value="" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="validationTooltip02">Order Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="orderDate" value="" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="validationTooltipUsername">Order Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model="orderStatus" value="" readonly>
                     </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Customer Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="11" wire:model="custPhone"  readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Customer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="11" wire:model="custName"  readonly>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                @foreach($serviceOrder as $o)
                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Service {{ $loop->iteration }} </label>
                        <input type="text"  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.serv.serviceName" class="form-control " readonly>
                       
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden"  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.serv.servicePrice" class="form-control col-sm-1 mb-3" readonly>
                   
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Weight/Size</label>
                        <input type="text" name="" value=""  wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.weightsize"  class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3"> 
                        <label class="form-control-label" >Quantity*opt</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" value="" wire:model="serviceOrder.{{ $loop->index }}.quantity"  class="form-control" @if(!$serviceOrder[$loop->index]['quantity']) readonly @endif >
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                </div>
                    
                    <label class="form-control-label" >Order Total RM</label>
                    <input type="number" wire:model="orderTotal" value="" class="form-control" readonly>
                    
                     </br>
                                         
                <div class="form-actions">  
                <div class="container" style="padding: 0;margin: 0;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" >
                    <span class="float-sm-left">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('orders.indexInProcess') }}"> Back</a>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <span class="float-sm-right">
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mr-2">Update</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-dark float-right">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                 </form>
                </div>
                </div>
```

here is the livewire updates.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Livewire;

 use Livewire\Component;
 use App\Customer;
 use App\Service;
 use App\Order;
 use App\ServiceOrder;

 class Updates extends Component
 {
 public $orders;
public $orderID;
public $orderDate;
public $orderStatus;
public $orderTotal;
public $custName;
public $custPhone;
public $serviceName;
public $servicePrice;
public $weightsize;
public $quantity;
public $serviceOrder;


public function mount($order,$so)
{
    //$orders = Order::with('customer')->get();
    //ServiceOrder::with('serv')->where('order_id', $order->id)->get();
    $this->orderID = $order->id;
    $this->orderDate = $order->orderDate;
    $this->orderStatus = $order->orderStatus;
    $this->orderTotal = $order->orderTotal;
    $this->custPhone = $order->customer->custPhone;
    $this->custName = $order->customer->custName;
    $this->serviceOrder = $so->toArray();
    //dd($this->serviceOrder);
    //$so->serviceName,
    //$so->weightsize,
    //$so->quantity 

}

public function render()
{
    //$so = ServiceOrder::with('serv')->where('order_id', $order->id)->get();
    return view('livewire.updates');
}

public function updatedInputs($name)
{
    
    $array = explode('.', $name);
    if ($array[1] == 'serviceName') {
        $this->inputs[$array[0]]['servicePrice'] = $this->services->find($value)->servicePrice;
    }
    try {
        $this->calculateTotal();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }
}

 // perform calculation here.
 public function calculateTotal(){
    $this->orderTotal =  $this->orderTotal;
        foreach ($this->serviceOrder as $item) {
            if($item['quantity'] == ''){
                $item['optQuantity']= 1;
                $this->orderTotal += ($item['servicePrice'] * $item['weightsize']) * ($item['quantity']);
                
            }else{
                $this->orderTotal += $item['servicePrice'] * ($item['weightsize']) * ($item['quantity']);
                
            }
               
                //$this->total *=  $item['optQuantity']; // * price;
        }
    }
  }
```

please help me out here T.T

Answer (score 0):

You can fire event from component (for example) and then register listener in class and call a method for updating total. Check [documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) for that.

Answer (score 0):

"Apparently, there is a value already in the Order Total (since it is an update) so i want it to auto update the value in the order total when the user update the new input in weight/size or quantity."

So, the problem is **$orderTotal only update once? it doesn't update when user update new input?**. Livewire should render everytime there is action or any input.

First of all, i advice u to check what happen when to your function when user update the new input with dd function.

```
public function calculateTotal(){
    dd('is this func work?');
    $this->orderTotal =  $this->orderTotal;
        foreach ($this->serviceOrder as $item) {
            if($item['quantity'] == ''){
                $item['optQuantity']= 1;
                $this->orderTotal += ($item['servicePrice'] * $item['weightsize']) * ($item['quantity']);
                
            }else{
                $this->orderTotal += $item['servicePrice'] * ($item['weightsize']) * ($item['quantity']);
                
            }
               
                //$this->total *=  $item['optQuantity']; // * price;
        }
    }
```

After you debug your function, maybe you already found the answer you looking for or you can come back and ask me anything. ^^